# asp.net mvc ModelBinder always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i've model binder in my asp.net mvc 4 site.

```
public class OptionModelBinder : System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder
        {         
            private const string SessionKey = "Opt";
            public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllercontext, System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
            {

                    Option opt = (Option)controllercontext.HttpContext.Session[SessionKey];
                    if (opt == null)
                    {
                        opt = new Option ();
                        controllercontext.HttpContext.Session[SessionKey] = opt ;

                    }
                    return opt;
                 }
        }
```

And Controller:

```
publick ActionResult Index(Option currentOption)
{
//currentOption always null
}
```

I'm sure it worked before. Something happened because of the recent updates Solution.
I do not understand what is wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check **Application_Start** method in **Global.asax.cs**
Make sure that there is that something like a

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add (typeof (Option), new OptionModelBinder ());
```

it is necessarily

Comment: Ahh...two hours blank( Thanks